# I have activity_main with 2 button in Linear Layout. And i want this layout in ActionBar with icons

Tags: android, android-actionbar

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/action_home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/action_exit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Ok" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want this layout to be addded in ActionBar. Also I want to add icons in the button.

Comment: Please describe the steps you took to solve this problem on your own, prior to posting the question on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want this layout to be addded in ActionBar

Inflate your layout and add it as a custom vie to the action bar

```
ActionBar.LayoutParams lp = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
View customView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customNav, lp); // or getActionBar()
```

> Also I want to add icons in the button
>   Use

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon"
```

or

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon"
```

to add icons on button

Comment: In LayoutParams, it is showing multiple choices, Alt + Enter, Which one should I use from the list.

Comment: For `LayoutParams`?  Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, all LayoutParams are red and it asks for to choose multiple LayoutParams choices, like widget.radiogroup.LayoutParams.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me.